# change margin if margin < "0px"

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I use this code

```
function moveContent(px) {
    var top = $('.scroll').position().top;

    $('.scroll').css('top', top+px);
}

function keyHandler(event)
{
    try
    {
        //some code here...

        else if (code == stb.KEY_PPLUS)
            moveContent(20); 
        else if (code == stb.KEY_PMINUS)
            moveContent(-20);

        //some code here...
```

And I have a point, the block moves out of the screen.
I think that I need something like this

```
if ($(".elementClass").css("margin-top")<'200px'){
    //don't move content in this direction
}
```

Comment: And where(in which block of code) is your problem?

Comment: Second one. I don't know, what I should write. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
// get the margin in integer form
var margin=parseInt($(".elementClass").css("margin-top").replace('px',''));
if (margin < 200){
    //don't move content in this direction
} else{
    // whatever you want in else part...
}
```